# Is there a way to change the UI behavior of Eclipse Preference Page?

Tags: eclipse, preference

I am developing an plug-in, I want to change the UI of the Eclipse Preference page, for example, I want to change the color of "General" to red. May I ask that is it possible? If so, could you give me some hints of how to do it? Thanks very much.

Comment: If you mean the items in the tree on the left of the dialog I don't see a way to do this.

Comment: You meant that for the contents on the right, it is possible?

Comment: NO, I mean I only looked at the source code for the tree on the left. It is unlikely to be possible for existing preference pages on the right.